# Load first page onload and first nav button clicked onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, css

First hello to all. I am relatively new to jquery and on a learning curve.

My script is this:

```js
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(function () {
$('#content').find('#nav a').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var page = $(this).attr('href');
$('#content2').load(page);
});
});
$(function() >{
$('#content').find('#nav a').click(function() {
$('#nav a').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');              
});
});
</script
```

```html
<div id="content">
 <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="x.svg" />
 <div id="svgfix">
     <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="1.svg" />
     <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="2.svg" />
     <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="3.svg" />
     <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="4.svg" />
     <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="5.svg" />
     <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="6.svg" />
 </div>
 <div id="nav">
      <a href="1.htm"><img type="image/svg+xml" src="1.svg" /></a>
      <a href="2.htm"><img type="image/svg+xml" src="2.svg" /></a>
      <a href="3.htm"><img type="image/svg+xml" src="3.svg" /></a>
      <a href="4.htm"><img type="image/svg+xml" src="4.svg" /></a>
      <a href="5.htm"><img type="image/svg+xml" src="5.svg" /></a>
      <a href="6.htm"><img type="image/svg+xml" src="6.svg" /></a>
 </div>
 </div>
<div id="content2"><h1></h1></div>
```

The script works well. The only problem i have, i want the first page to auto load and the first button to be on selected. I have tried to find a solution here and read trough the topics, but nothing has worked so fare.

The script should load on click trough the nav bar with the 6 pages and it does and each button will be selected. But i would like on first page load, to auto select the first button and autoload the first page.

I hope my question is understandable and thanks for your time and help in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Create a function and call when the page is ready and on click event

```
$(function () {

function getPage(el){
var page = $(el).attr('href');
$('#content2').load(page);
$('#nav a').removeClass('selected');
$(el).addClass('selected'); 
}


 getPage($('#nav a:first-child'));//get the first page
$('#nav a').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
     getPage($(this));            
});
});
```

Comment: don't forget to check the green button to accept the answer :p

Comment: But sadly it works only on firefox and safari, chrome wont

Comment: Sorry it works on chrome aswell, it was because chrome does not accept local testing, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try triggering  click on first link after you create the event listeners

```
$('#nav a').first().click()
```

---

Quick note about your `find()`. Since ID's must be unique on a page you can skip `$('#content').find('#nav a')` and just use `$('#nav a')`

Comment: Were exactly do i add this small code, inside the first or the second function ?

Comment: After them...you need those event handlers created before you trigger the code inside them to run

Comment: i did the find, cause otherwise i cant reach the div inside the div, since there are two divs, and the div i need is inside another div.

Comment: $(function() {
          $('#content').find('#nav a').click(function() {
              $('#nav a').removeClass('selected');
              $(this).addClass('selected');
              $('#nav a').first().click()              
          });
      });

Comment: You mean something like this?

Comment: OK...but can't duplicate ID's...they are unique by definition

Comment: Think of it as ....when I click on something i need it to do.... now that I have that code I am going to trigger it

Comment: I dont understand duplicate ID, there are two different IDs, one is content and one is nav and if i add only nav a wont work. And i ave two click functions.

Comment: Should work just fine regardless of it being inside another div...as long as there is only one `#nav` in the page   and there ***must*** only be one.

Comment: Ok i did as you said, hmm it really works, maybe i had some css problem, but adding $('#nav a').first().click() inside the last function caused the page to load constandly over and over strange.

Comment: I keep telling you it goes ***after*** last function so it only gets called once when page loads

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand your question - maybe something like this?

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    var firstNav = $('#nav a').first();
    var page = firstNav.attr('href');
    $('#content2').load(page);
    firstNav.addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: There is only one nav with the 6 pages to be loaded on each click, and that works now. But i want on page load, to autoload the first page into the div  and the first button autoselected...

Comment: If the code in your question works as you want, I think the code above would do your "autoload" and "autoselect" on page load.